# How to find unneccesary dependencies in a maven multi-project?

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, module, modularity

If you are developing a large evolving multi module maven project it seems inevitable that there are some dependencies given in the poms that are unneccesary, since they are transitively included by other dependencies. For example this happens if you have a module A that originally includes C. Later you refactor and have A depend on a module B which in turn depends on C. If you are not careful enough you'll wind up with both B and C in A's dependency list. But of course you do not need to put C into A's pom, since it is included transitively, anyway. Is there tool to find such unneccesary dependencies?

(These dependencies do not actually hurt, but they might obscure your actual module structure and having less stuff in the pom is usually better. :-)

Answer (score 13):

To some extent you can use `dependency:analyze`, but it's not too helpful. Also check [JBoss Tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale).

Some time ago I've started a [maven-storyteller-plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MSTP/User+Guide) to be able to deeper analyze the poms, but the project is very far from production/public use. You can use the `storyteller:recount` goal to analyze the unused/redundant dependencies.

The problem with the whole story is - how to determine "unused" things. What is quite possible to analyze is for instance class references. But it won't work if you're using reflection - directly or non-directly.

**Update November 2014.**

I've just [moved my old code of the Storyteller plugin to GitHub](https://github.com/highsource/storyteller-maven-plugin). I'll refresh it and release to the central so that it's usable for others.

Answer (score 2):

I

personaly use the pom editor of M2Eclipse to visually view the dependency tree (2D tree). Then I give a look in my deliverable (war, ear) lib directories. Then still in M2Eclipse pom dependencies viewer I go to every 3rd party, and right click on the dependency I want to exclude (an exclusion is added automatically in the right dependency).

There is no golden rules, simply some basic tips:

a lot of pom are not correct: a lot of 3rd party libs out there require way too much dependencies in the default compile scope, if everybody carefully craft their pom, you must not have so much unwanted dependencies.

you need to guess by the name of dependencies what you will have to exclude, best example are parsers, transformer, documentbuilder: xalan, xerces, xalan alfred and co. try to remove them and use the internal jdk1.6 parser, common apache stuff, log4j is also worth looking at.

look also regularly in lib delivery if you do not have duplicate libraries with different version (the dependency resolver of maven should avoid that)

go bottom up, start with your common modules, then go up till the service layer, trimming down dependencies in every module, dont try to start in modules ear/war, it will be too difficult

check often if your deliverable are still working, by either testing or comparing and old deliverable with the new one (especially in web-inf/lib directory what has disappeared with winmerge/beyoncompare)

Comment: In case someone stumble upon this - a bit more elaborated and updated instructions are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907162/systematic-approach-with-maven-to-deal-with-dependency-hell

Answer (score 1):

When you have **A -> B, B -> C**, and then refactor such that **A -> (B, C)**. ***IF*** it is the case that **A** still compiles against **B**, you very much don't want to simply pick up the dependency because you receive it transitively.

Think of the case when **A -> (B-1.0, C-1.0), B-1.0 -> C-1.0**. Everything's in sync, so to avoid "duplication" you remove **C** from **A**'s dependency. Then you upgrade A to use **B-2.0 -> C-2.0**. You begin to see errors because **A** wants **C-1.0** classes but found **C-2.0** classes. While quickly reconcilable in this scenario, it is far less so when you have lots of dependencies.

You very much want the information in **A**'s pom that says that it explicitly expects to find **C-1.0** on the classpath so that you can understand when you have transitive dependency conflicts. Again, Maven will do the job of ensuring that the "closest" version of any particular jar ends up on your classpath. But when things go wrong - you want all the dependency metatdata you can get.

On a slightly more practical note, a dependency is unused when you can remove it from your pom and all of your unit/integration/acceptance tests still pass. ;-)

Comment: > ...a dependency is unused when you can remove it from your pom
> and all of your unit/integration/acceptance tests still pass...

This is correct, but gives no method for analysis. :)