# How to say to Maven which dependency to use

Tags: spring, maven, migration, ibatis

Right now I'm migrating legacy project from Spring 1 to bigger version (yeah I know it's 2017). The project has 1 dependency which contains a lot of spring/ibatis dependencies. One of ibatis dependency is version 2.1.6 but migrating spring requires bigger version(2.3.4) I put the new dependency in my pom but maven keeps using the old one. I know that it's not soo good to have 2 different version in the project and the main goal for me is to remove the old big dependency but right now I want to start the project with the new one without removing the old one.

How to tell maven which dependency to use and how to ignore the other one? If this is not possible tell me how to migrate easily.

Thank you.

Comment: share your pom.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Systematic approach with Maven to deal with dependency hell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907162/systematic-approach-with-maven-to-deal-with-dependency-hell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the `<exclusions>` tag under the `<dependency>` section of the pom.
[More Details here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

**Sample:**

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: here, Project-B is your ibatis older version and project-A is the one which contains ibatis older dependency.